# Three JS help, doesn't render on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

I am working on some school assignment, and we are to use textures and show some 3d transforms on cubes. 
Basically, I have all the code working, Until yesterday, it was running fine, until I made some change which has altered the output.

**Tech: HTML, CSS, JS, Jquery, THREE.js**

code: https://pastebin.com/TwERJL0w
website: http://www.cs.uml.edu/~svenkatr/assgnmnts/Assignment4/3dtransforms.html

So my problem is that. I have a div with id *Output*. output is appended with rendered.domElement. So everything works fine (I need a cube at the center of screen with functions on the leftside). But when my document loads, I get a black cube. The cube texture doesn't load, nor does the cube properly. I think this is some bug in THREE js.

As soon as I run a function such as a 3d Rotation or scale, or even begin animating the cube, the cube renders fine. Until some user input the cube fails to load. I do not understand why.

My request to you is that go through my code once and tell me what kind of logical errors or wrong practices you find in my code which is causing it.

**what I tried:** Yeah so I tried to call all the functions at the end of the `$(document).ready();` one by one, to check if the cube renders then on load. But it doesn't. It only works with the buttons I have provided. Using chrome's developer mode, in the *console*, if I put `renderer.render(scene, camera)`, it renders fine, upon load.

*I think it is a small error or logical error which is causing this.*

**On a side note, how do I delay calls to rendering the cube until textures are loaded or its completely loaded?!**

Comment: looks a bit confusing, but, if your `animate` flag is false, you never issue a drawcall, once you animate, you start rendering, but once you stop you probably have the last rendered frame in the buffer. Hence you thinking it should work at that point. Just call a `renderer.render()` when you're done instantiating the cube. Remove the texture to see if that works.

Comment: Please include your code in the body of the post. If your links die, so does the context of our question.

Comment: Solved because I used `rendered.info.render.calls` and i got 0. That showed that there was no call to render. But I had placed calls in init(). But by placing the call into animate. It renders on start and places 6 calls to render. 
So ultimately, dont call render in init. definitely some bug or some misunderstanding. Because it wouldn't render how many ever calls I placed except the animate, and mostly it is cause we call `requestAnimationFrame()` in animate.

Comment: As a side note, you can also introduce a loading manager into your app. See https://threejs.org/docs/api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager.html